# how do i make a button generate a random number and each time the button is clicked a new number is generated and added to the previous number

Tags: javascript, random

I need help making a button generate a random number in java script, i would like when the button is pressed for it to generate a random number between 1-10 and and then once the button is pressed again for it to generate a new random number but the sum of both number to show each time the button is presses. For example *button is presses and the computer generates 3 button is presses and computer generates 2 but shows the sum of 2+3 so 5*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merienda+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


<title>
    Blackjack
</title>

<body>


    <head>
        <h1>
            <i>BLACKJACK</i>
        </h1>
        <h4>
            Computers Cards:
            <input type="text" id="computerscards">
            <br>Player 1 cards:
            <input type="text" id="playerscards">
        </h4>
    </head>

    <input type="button" value="start" onclick="document.getElementById('playerscards').value = 
    random();document.getElementById('computerscards').value = 18">


    <input type="button" value="deal" onclick="document.getElementById('playerscards).value = dealcard">

    <input type="button" value="stand" onclick="">

    <input type="button" value="next" onclick="">


    <p>Press hit if you would like to draw another card
        <br> press stand if you do not wish to draw another card
        <br> press next if you want to start the next round</p>


</body>

<script src="java.js"></script>

</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var total = 
var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1); 

function random() { 
    return randomnumber; 
} 

function dealcard() { }
```

Comment: What is wrong with what you have now?

Comment: sorry it is not clear, i need my "deal button to generate the random number and the number to be summed when the button is pressed.

Comment: Whenever you post on Stack Overflow please make sure to post what you have already tried, and make sure that you aren't asking for "Homework Solving". Also, try and make sure you ask specific questions, ie. "How can I sum an array?", "How do I add the result of Math.random to an Array". If you know what you want, but have _no_ idea how you could possibly get there, maybe try and think of the underlying components of what you want first, and then ask specific questions to help _you_ achieve _your_ goal.

Answer (score 0):

When you set `var total =` multiple times, you are **overwriting** that variable. Instead, you should be setting it as a static value of `0` to start with, and updating it **inside** of the function that you call on button click. You can add to the existing value with `total +=`, which is a shorthand way of saying `total = total + ...`.

Here's a really stripped-down example showcasing this:

```js
var total = 0;

function dealcard() {
  total += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
  document.getElementById('playerscards').value = total;
}
```

```html
Player 1 cards: <input type="text" id="playerscards">
<br />
<button onclick="dealcard()">Deal</button>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what i am looking for :)

Comment: just another question how do i link the code you have sent me to my id called playerscards